# Reload the iframe when new url is assigned (Angular5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

In my angular application, I am taking input from the user. The value of the selected input is passed to URL which is then assigned to the iframe.

```
<div class="form-group row">                                                                                                  
<label >Select: </label>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<select (change)="onchange($event)" class="custom-select">                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<option value="value1">item1</option>                                                                                                               
<option value="value2">item2</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</select>                                                                                                   
</div>
```

This is where I am asking the user to select one option and the value of the selected option is assigned to the URL.

```
onchange(e:Event){

this.option = e.target['value'];
this.url = `${this.option}/remainingurl...`;
}
```

option stores the value of the user input and then option is assigned to url.

```
<div  class="card-body">
<div class="iframe-container" >
<iframe Content="no-cache" [src]='url' scrolling="no" >
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

This is loading the iframe properly for the first time. But next time when the user selects another option, the iframe is not getting updated. I checked whether the iframe is getting latest URL and it is getting a new one. But still, iframe is not loading the changed page. 
I also went through few solutions online and they said it might be cache issue and I tried adding **Content="no-cache"**  in HTML code but still, it didn't work.

Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this issue??

Comment: You have any error in console ?

Comment: working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrpsdi

Comment: working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqbgx8

Comment: @EbinManuval I am not getting any error in console